# Inheriting from base class in different assembly

Tags: c#, inheritance, factory

I use a generic base class and derived classes that implement specific instances with their own specialist individual dependencies.  I don't want developers to have to install all the dependencies, only the ones they need, so I put the derived classes in their own assemblies \ dlls.  I then use a factory that creates the correct instance depending on parameters passed in.  All calls against that returned instance need to get routed to the correct derived method.  Only that isn't working.  They get routed to the base class methods instead.  Is there a way to configure this?  It worked fine when they were in the same assembly.

Comment: Please give a short but complete example which demonstrates theproblem. Are you *sure* you're overriding the method appropriately?

Comment: did you declare your methods virtual?

Comment: This sounds like a case for (drumroll)... interfaces and IoC.